# How to fix git config issue where all commands go to blank line?

Tags: macos, git, configuration

I am not new to git but I am newer to github and still a beginner with bash. I was trying to set some config stuff and ending up breaking git on my local machine. Here's what I did following [these instructions on github for password caching](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git).

```
$ git config --global user.name 'myusername'
$ git config --global user.email 'myemail@email.com'
$ git credential-osxkeychain
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
$ curl -s -O http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain
$ chmod u+x git-credential-osxkeychain
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/bin/git
$ git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
^?^C
```

After this command git I received no response, just a new line which I eventually ctrl+c'ed out of. Now, whenever I do a git command in *any* repo, not just this one, the cursor just moves to a new line. I'm unable to push/pull/clone or do use of the commands I normally use.

I've tried reinstalling the latest version of git and still have the problem. What should I do?

**Update:**

I've tried unsetting credential.helper and uninstalling and reinstalling git. Still seeing the same behavior. I noticed that if I run just `$ git` the response is `Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>`. At this point, I just want to delete credential-osxkeychain. Still unsuccessful.

As requested, the output of which -a git is:

```
$ which -a git
/usr/bin/git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
```

Comment: Whoever voted for this being off topic: VCS questions are on-topic on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ran this command:

```
$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain /usr/bin/git
```

You overwrote the existing `git` executable with the `git-credential-osxkeychain` executable. That script is only meant to be run as a sub-command of Git, not standalone.

If you use Time Machine, you can try to restore the old `/usr/bin/git` from a backup. Otherwise, you'll need to reinstall Git.

---

Based on the comments below, it appears that `/usr/bin/git` is actually still `git-credential-osxkeychain`, probably because Git installed itself into `/usr/local` instead of `/usr/bin`.

If you don't care about the keychain behavior anymore, you can remove the current `git` executable altogether:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/git
```

That may cause Git to start working for you immediately if `/usr/local/git/bin` is in your path. Or you could simply move it to `/usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain`:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
```

which (again, assuming your path is correct) should allow you to use it as a credential helper like you originally wanted.

Comment: Interesting... you must be right. Reinstalling git hasn't helped me so far. It looks like my machine is hanging on to the credential-osxkeychain somehow.

Comment: What's the output of `which -a git`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/git /usr/local/git/bin/git`

Comment: I added another couple of suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Your second suggestions were exactly what I needed to understand. Thank you!